# Beer Ranking Tournament

Tags: machine-learning, statistics, ranking, bayesian

I would like to invite a number of friends over for a beer ranking tournament. Every attendee will be asked to bring a 'bomber' (1 pint) of the best beer they can find. Let F be a vector of friends who attend the party, and B be a vector of the beers. B necessarily has more elements than F because every participant must bring at least one beer.

I would like to write an algorithm (most likely in excel/vis basic) that assigns each friend 4 beers to rank. I think the best way for the rankings is to rate the beers 1-4. Then, based on the rankings, I would like to rank all of the beers best to worst.

How can I best rank all of the beers with each person trying only four?

Comment: Do you only have 1 bottle of each beer? In other words, will beers be ranked by more than one person?

Comment: Nope each beer will be ranked by 4 people.. each person will have 1/4 of 4 different beers

Comment: Sorry, I don't follow -- you have 4 bottles of each type of beer? And everyone tastes one bottle of each type?

Answer (score 0):

My thought process towards the above problem is outlined below:

*NOTE:  The Solution assumes that there are at least five participants for the problem.*

1. The participants are randomly allocated a position
2. The participants sit at the nominated position on the table with the beer that they brought.
3. The participants rotate clockwise, taste 1/4 pint of beer, and repeats the process four times
4. The participants rank each of the four beers that they tasted
5. The scores are sorted to assign a rank for each of the beers

Drink Responsibly.